# OSX: how to determine USB current draw?

Tags: macos, command-line, usb

I connected a device to my USB port, but it's unclear how much current it is drawing. Is there a way from the command line, or otherwise, to determine how much current that device is drawing?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but maybe helpful: Using `System Information` and then checking your USB devices you can see the available and required current per USB device.

Comment: That’s just a number in the report that the USB device declares on initialization, its clearly not displaying the instantaneous current draw... I think you would need to make a spliced usb connector and get your multimeter in there in series and you can have an accurate reading. Also they make inline usb power meters. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00J3JSEG6/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awd_EGZCwbR22GY5V

Answer (score 1):

It's not likely that Apple would invest in ammeter circuitry in the usb power lines and connect it to the computer motherboard.

It's likely there **is** some form of current overload prevention (I wouldn't even know what. A polyfuse maybe?), but it wouldn't be something accessible to the operating system.

Current draw information will more likely than not require additional hardware to obtain.